# ELM : error while embedding ( List of HTML ) in div second argument

Tags: elm

Given a List of String , I want to create a List of HTML div in order to inject it in view :
I wondered that the function signature should be as following :

```
display : List String ->  List Html div
```

and the function body :

```
    display model = case model of
     [] -> []
     (x::xs) -> div [][ text x] :: display xs
```

when embeding the above function in the view as per the below (as i know the  **div** function take a List of Html as second argument `div : List Attribute -> List Html -> Html`)

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
   view model = div []
                  [
                    input [ placeholder "write your post here" , onInput  Change][]
                    , button [onClick Save ][text "save"]
                    ,div [][ display model.lst ]
```

I am getting the below error when compiling :

```
  The 2nd argument to function `div` is causing a mismatch.

24|                      div [][ display model.lst ]
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Function `div` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:

    List (VirtualDom.Node a)

But it is:

    List (List (Html a))
```

how could I sort this out , THANKS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message about the line `div [][ display model.lst ]` states that you are trying to embed a list within a list. Since the return value of `display` is already a list, you don't need to wrap it in brackets. Try this instead:

```elm
div [] (display model.lst)
```

You'll then see that there is a problem with the type annotation for `display`. You are missing some parentheses, because `List` only takes a single type argument. It should be:

```elm
display : List String ->  List (Html div)
```

And as a side note, in that signature for `display`, you have `Html div`. That `div` doesn't mean it's returning an actual div. A lowercase label in a type annotation basically means that anything can go there. You'll often see people use short-hand type labels for that, like `Html a`, since entering `div` there can be confusing. Another alternative is being consistent with the rest of the view code and using `Html Msg`. Either way, in this particular circumstance, is fine; it's just a matter of convention.

Comment: thank you for your information , I find this " A lowercase label in a type annotation basically means that anything can go there" a bit confusing, could elaborate please

Comment: Upper and Lowercase values in Elm are significant in a few ways. Take a look at the [Reading Types](http://guide.elm-lang.org/types/reading_types.html) section of the guide.